# Remove words from the SYSTEMS predictive dictionary

Tags: keyboard, text-prediction

On my *Wileyfox Swift,* the pre-installed keyboard is called "AOSP keyboard". It allows to type and to "swipe". When set to German, and I "swipe" the word "mal" (you can compare that to the English "just"), which happens quite often, in 90% of the cases text prediction replaces it by "NSKK". At fist I was irritated, then annoyed. Finally I looked up the term, which up to then told me nothing, and found out it's an abbreviation for the "national socialists motor corps" (Nationalsozialistisches Kraftfahrkorps) – and now I even feel offended.

I tried and checked:

- no such term in any of my "user dictionaries" (I had wondered if)
- [Editing the built-in autocorrect dictionary in AOSP keyboard](/q/110157/16575) suggests to unpack, edit and repack the APK – which for me (and most users) is no option
- [Where's the stock keyboard's predictive dictionary located?](/q/22456/16575) mostly speaks about the user dictionaries, also mentions the *source* for the stock dictionaries, and one user reports (in 4/2012, so not sure if it still applies) where he found the files on-device – but no way how to edit them
- [Delete words from the built-in dictionary?](/q/128883/16575) (2015) never got an answer
- Most other questions here talk about specific keyboards like Swype
- hints I found in several posts (like long-pressing the predicted word should bring up a possibility to delete it, or correcting it often enough should make the system deem it "more important") did not work out.

**Is there any way to get rid of those stupid predictions?** I'm fine with solutions requiring root, even if it comes to edit some SQLite database. Imagine every time you typed "just" it would turn into "KKK", it's a horror…

In case it matters: my *Swift* still runs on its original CyanogenOS 12.1 (Android 5.1), as I didn't wish to go MM with it (and specifically not Nougat, as it has no XPosed).